# How can I do a SELECT for a subquery that has returned more than one value?

Tags: sql

I have a problem with using SQL in a database.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier 
(
    Supplier_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Phone int,
    Email varchar(50) 
);

CREATE TABLE Batchofmeat 
(
    Number_of_batch varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Supplier_ID int NOT NULL REFERENCES Supplier(Supplier_ID),
    Weight FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Temperature FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Price FLOAT NOT NULL
); 

SELECT Email 
FROM Supplier 
WHERE (SELECT Temperature FROM Batchofmeat 
       WHERE Supplier.Supplier_ID = Batchofmeat.Supplier_ID) < 3;
```

The problem is that when I run the `SELECT`, I get the following error:

> The subquery has returned more than one value, which is not correct when following =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when used as an expression

Even if I get the error it should show the solution, what could be the problem?

What I want with my select is to select the email address of those suppliers whose `Batchofmeat` have a temperature below 3°C.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: What is supposed to be that magic number `3`?

Comment: What do you ***want*** to happen?  Describe it using examples,as directed by this; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: As an aside, you should probably be using `decimal/numeric` and not `float`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find all records with a temperature less than 3 you can use the following.

```
SELECT Email 
FROM Supplier 
WHERE Supplier_ID IN (SELECT Temperature FROM Batchofmeat WHERE Supplier.Supplier_ID = Batchofmeat.Supplier_ID AND Temperature < 3 );
```

Note, that this may not be performant with a large number of records.

Answer (score 0):

If could use `avg`, `max`, or `min` temperature if that meets your business requirements.

```
SELECT Email 
  FROM Supplier 
 WHERE 
   (
      SELECT avg(Temperature)
        FROM Batchofmeat 
       WHERE Supplier.Supplier_ID = Batchofmeat.Supplier_ID
   ) < 3;
```

Having said that, I would write the SQL query like this:

```
SELECT Supplier_ID, Email, avg(Temperature)
  FROM Supplier inner join Batchofmeat using (Supplier_ID)
 group by Supplier_ID, Email
having avg(Temperature) < 3;
```

UPDATE:

Per your comment: *What I want with my select is to select the email address of those suppliers whose Batchofmeat have a temperature below 3°C. –*

Do this:

```
SELECT distinct Supplier_ID, Email
  FROM Supplier inner join Batchofmeat using (Supplier_ID)
 where Temperature < 3;
```

Comment: What I want with my select is to select the email address of those suppliers whose Batchofmeat have a temperature below 3°C.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding conditions such as:  `temperature <3` in your query it is possible that there could be multiple values that meet this criteria. Hence you will have to use the `in` operator here.

`in` acts like a list of values.

```
SELECT Email FROM Supplier 
WHERE Supplier_ID IN (SELECT Temperature FROM Batchofmeat 
                      WHERE Supplier.Supplier_ID =  Batchofmeat.Supplier_ID AND Temperature < 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `exists` is all you require here:

```
select email
from supplier s
where exists (select * from BatchOfMeat b where b.temperature < 3 and b.Supplier_Id=s.Supplier_Id )
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed, just what you said, my mistake was not to put the exist.